# java programming

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Usage patterns for private, static, final, public, abstract keywords in java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083232/usage-patterns-for-private-static-final-public-abstract-keywords-in-java)
>   [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

what is the difference between the abstract, public, private classes?

Comment: Have you searched this site before asking?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083232/usage-patterns-for-private-static-final-public-abstract-keywords-in-java

Comment: -1 (I would highly recommend a Java book/tutorial -- lists of such can be found on SO as well.)

Comment: @Jim it's not an *exact* duplicate if you read the other one.  The other OP is asking for *usage patterns* and states from the start that he knows what they mean (except for abstract).

Answer (score 1):

Public classes are accessible from all other classes, whereas private classes are only accessible from within the class itself.  [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is a good summary of the Java visibilities:

```
Modifier        Class     Package   Subclass  World
public          Y         Y         Y         Y
protected       Y         Y         Y         N
no modifier     Y         Y         N         N
private         Y         N         N         N
```

Abstract classes are a bit of a different beast.  An abstract class is one that cannot be instantiated.  In other words, you cannot invoke `new` on an abstract class; you would need to do so an a concrete sub-class.